# How to show indicators in top panel in ubuntu 20.04.3?

Tags: panel, gnome-panel, sensors, lm-sensors

I have ubuntu 20.04.3. What i want is basically small graphical icons and then some sensors values, like cpu and ram usage percentage, cpu and gpu temp, network up/down speeds

What I've tried

- `sudo apt install sensors-applet`
  top panel is not right clickable, cannot find a way to do "Add to panel" stuff (probably its for older versions, and newer graphical ui was just broken by bad developers and lacks this feature. Program is also missing in all Applications, no observable way to launch this stuff.
- `sudo apt install psensor` Is displaying only one icon. Cannot get it to display multiple things in notification bar. Also lacks memory usage percentage and network bandwidth display possibility.
- `sudo apt install indicator-multiload` can display only unclear graphs or single line of text, which flickers when you have cpu usage 0% then 10% all text after is going back and forth, renders that very bad. Also cant get temperatures.

So many time passed, there should be a modern indicator, its so common task, right? What would you use if you need several icons and sensor values in top panel in regular ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my friend in our workspace just helped me, he is using vitals shell extension!

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/

this is instruction how to install extensions:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop

to conveniently install extensions there is a browser integration:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep/related?hl=en

Comment: Also works perfectly on 22.04.